# How to access kinect audio device using libfreenect correctly

Tags: linux, audio, kinect, openkinect

I use an Kinect, Model 1517, and cloned the master branch from the OpenKinect/libfreenect repo to my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64.
My target is to do some fancy stuff with the build in mic-array.

But if I want to test the sources and execute a sample program, I get following output :

```
$ ./freenect-glview 
Kinect camera test
Number of devices found: 1
Could not open audio: -1
Failed to open motor subddevice or it is not disabled.Failed to open audio subdevice or it is not disabled.Could not open device
```

During compilation no error or warning is pointed out. With debugging I isolated the failure to the initialization of FREENECT_DEVICE_MOTOR.

I also tried to download the stable package version, using

```
$ sudo apt-get install freenect
```

but (not in freenect-glview but in other samples) this error occurs too.

What differs from all the tutorials and guides I read, is that after the command `$lsusb` the output just shows three devices named 'Microsoft Corp.', instead of a longer description like `Bus 001 Device 006: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio`.

Do you have any plans, how I can fix this Problem? I assume, if it doesn't work in these samples, that it also wont work in an selfmade one.

Answer (score 2):

Try running with administrator privileges. I had the same problem and that worked for me.

```
$ sudo ./freenect-glview
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but doesn't work for me.. :(

Comment: freenect-glview works, but with no mention of the audio (microphone) array in the source code.